# Typescript: Initialize an empty NodeListOf

Tags: typescript

I am struggling in TS with `querySelectorAll`. I want to access any HTML element with this selector, no matter if it is a button, input and so on.

For `querySelector` I did something like this (which works fine):

```
function selector(element: HTMLElement, selector: string): HTMLElement | null {
    return element.querySelector(selector);
}

const element: HTMLElement | null = selector(document.body, '.my-button');
```

This is my similar method for `querySelectorAll`:

```
function selectorAll(element: HTMLElement, selector: string): NodeListOf<HTMLElement> {
    return element.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>(selector);
}
```

Now my issue is that I can not initialize an empty node list.
For example:

```
let buttons: NodeListOf<HTMLElement> = [];
buttons = selectorAll(document.body, 'button');
```

The compiler says: **The property 'item' is missing in type 'never[]' but required in type 'NodeListElement'.**

So what is the correct syntax for initializing an empty `NodeListOf` type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way to create an object with the `NodeList` interface other than calling `querySelectorAll` and related DOM APIs.

One alternative is to use array instead of `NodeList`.

```js
let buttons: Array<HTMLElement> = [];
buttons = Array.from(selectorAll(document.body, 'button'));
```

Answer (score 0):

To make `return element.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>(selector);` return an array instead of a NodeList, you could write it like this:

```
 return [...element.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>(selector)];
```